# Flutter Advance pdf viewer plugin works fine in emulator but in real device it shows error

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am completely a beginer in flutter .I have developing an app which shows pdf from local storage and store it in local db.when I am running in Emulator it works fine but when runing in real device  it shows error I using **Advance pdf viewer plugin** I also create proguard-rues.pro file also. can any help me solve this issue.

**Here is my pdf fetching code**

```
FilePickerResult  pdf = await FilePicker.platform
    .pickFiles(type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['pdf']);


_pdf = File(pdf.files.single.path);
doc = await PDFDocument.fromFile(_pdf);
```

**MyPdf Docviewer code**

```
                  Container(

                            width: 120,
                            height: 120,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: PDFViewer(
                              document: doc,
                              
                            ),
                          )
```

**My proguard rules.pro file**

```
     -keep class com.shockwave.**
     -keepclassmembers class com.shockwave.** { *; }
```

**My android build gradle file**

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```

}

**My android manifest file**

```
 FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
 <application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Error message while running in real device

```
  D/FilePickerUtils(22253): Allowed file extensions mimes: [application/pdf]
D/FilePickerDelegate(22253): Selected type */*
I/SurfaceView(22253): updateWindow -- onWindowVisibilityChanged, visibility = 8, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 Changes: creating=false format=false size=false visible=true left=false top=false mUpdateWindowNeeded=false mReportDrawNeeded=false redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=false mVisible=true mRequestedVisible=false, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0xce7fd99, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 New surface: Surface(name=null)/@0xb61c85e, vis=false, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 480, 854), this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 visibleChanged -- surfaceDestroyed, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): surfaceDestroyed callback +, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
D/GraphicBuffer(22253): register, handle(0x86399440) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
D/Surface (22253): Surface::disconnect(this=0x9038d700,api=1)
D/GraphicBuffer(22253): unregister, handle(0x86398300) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
D/GraphicBuffer(22253): unregister, handle(0x86398480) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
D/GraphicBuffer(22253): unregister, handle(0x86399440) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
D/Surface (22253): Surface::disconnect(this=0x9038d700,api=1)
I/SurfaceView(22253): surfaceDestroyed callback -, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
V/SurfaceView(22253): Layout: x=0 y=0 w=480 h=854, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 480, 854), this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
D/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 windowPositionLostRT RT, frameNr = 0
D/Surface (22253): Surface::disconnect(this=0x9038fa00,api=1)
D/GraphicBuffer(22253): unregister, handle(0x9172aec0) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
D/GraphicBuffer(22253): unregister, handle(0x9172b040) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
D/GraphicBuffer(22253): unregister, handle(0x9172af80) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
D/Surface (22253): Surface::disconnect(this=0x9038fa00,api=1)
V/PhoneWindow(22253): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = ViewRoot{bfd9ce3 com.example.detailscollector/com.example.detailscollector.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this = DecorView@be0ade5[MainActivity]
I/SurfaceView(22253): updateWindow -- onWindowVisibilityChanged, visibility = 4, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/FilePickerUtils(22253): Caching from URI: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3389
V/PhoneWindow(22253): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = ViewRoot{bfd9ce3 com.example.detailscollector/com.example.detailscollector.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this = DecorView@be0ade5[MainActivity]
D/ActivityThread(22253): isAppLocked r.intent.getComponent().getPackageName() = com.example.detailscollector
D/ActivityThread(22253): isAppLocked r.intent.getComponent() = ComponentInfo{com.example.detailscollector/com.example.detailscollector.MainActivity}
I/SurfaceView(22253): updateWindow -- onWindowVisibilityChanged, visibility = 0, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 Changes: creating=false format=false size=false visible=true left=false top=false mUpdateWindowNeeded=false mReportDrawNeeded=false redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=false mVisible=false mRequestedVisible=true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0xce7fd99, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 New surface: Surface(name=null)/@0xb61c85e, vis=true, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 480, 854), this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 visibleChanged -- surfaceCreated, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): surfaceCreated callback +, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
D/Surface (22253): Surface::connect(this=0x9038fa00,api=1)
W/libEGL  (22253): [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
D/mali_winsys(22253): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
I/SurfaceView(22253): surfaceCreated callback -, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 surfaceChanged -- format=4 w=480 h=854, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): surfaceChanged callback +, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): surfaceChanged callback -, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 surfaceRedrawNeeded, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
I/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 finishedDrawing, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
V/SurfaceView(22253): Layout: x=0 y=0 w=480 h=854, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 480, 854), this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
D/OpenGLRenderer(22253): CanvasContext() 0x90237000 initialize window=0x9038f300, title=com.example.detailscollector/com.example.detailscollector.MainActivity
D/Surface (22253): Surface::connect(this=0x9038f300,api=1)
W/libEGL  (22253): [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
V/InputMethodManager(22253): onWindowFocus: io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{bebe62d VFE...... .F...... 0,0-480,854} softInputMode=16 first=true flags=#81810100
D/mali_winsys(22253): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
I/SurfaceView(22253): Punch a hole(dispatchDraw), this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{959c544 V.E...... ........ 0,0-480,854}
D/SurfaceView(22253): 156878148 updateWindowPosition RT, frameNr = 1, postion = [0, 0, 480, 854]
D/GraphicBuffer(22253): register, handle(0x9172af80) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
D/GraphicBuffer(22253): register, handle(0x9172b4c0) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
D/GraphicBuffer(22253): register, handle(0x9172b040) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
D/FilePickerUtils(22253): File loaded and cached at:/data/user/0/com.example.detailscollector/cache/file_picker/96842
D/FilePickerDelegate(22253): File path:[com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker.FileInfo@a9b953c]
I/flutter (22253): pdf file
I/flutter (22253): found
I/art     (22253): Enter while loop.
I/art     (22253): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15207(1053KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 23MB/23MB, paused 1.951ms total 108.250ms
I/art     (22253): Enter while loop.
I/System.out(22253): length=5; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
W/System.err(22253): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
W/System.err(22253):    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
W/System.err(22253):    at pt.tribeiro.flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.getFileNameFromPath(FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.java:125)
W/System.err(22253):    at pt.tribeiro.flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.createTempPreview(FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.java:130)
W/System.err(22253):    at pt.tribeiro.flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.getPage(FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.java:170)
W/System.err(22253):    at pt.tribeiro.flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.access$100(FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.java:29)
W/System.err(22253):    at pt.tribeiro.flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin$1.run(FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.java:70)
W/System.err(22253):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
W/System.err(22253):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
W/System.err(22253):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
W/System.err(22253):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
D/GraphicBuffer(22253): register, handle(0x9172b580) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
Invalid argument(s) (path): Must not be null

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ArgumentError.checkNotNull (dart:core/errors.dart:194:27)
#1      _File._checkNotNull (dart:io/file_impl.dart:641:19)
#2      new _File (dart:io/file_impl.dart:205:17)
#3      new File (dart:io/file.dart:250:18)
#4      _PDFPageState._repaint (package:advance_pdf_viewer/src/page.dart:47:26)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 259 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PDFViewer file:///C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/New%20folder/12-11-2020-detailscollector/lib/create.dart:200:40
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .pickFiles(type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['pdf']);
```

change To:

```
FilePickerResult  pdf = await FilePicker.platform
    .pickFiles(type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['.pdf']);
```

This should resolve the issue. if not then show some code of `create.dart` line 190 to 210 by modifying your question.

Comment: the main error  was                                                                                              
     The following ArgumentError was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
Invalid argument(s) (path): Must not be null

Answer (score 0):

Here is my uploading function

```
void selectpdf() async {
 pdf = await FilePicker.platform
    .pickFiles(type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['pdf']);
_pdf = File(pdf.files.single.path);

);

doc = await PDFDocument.fromFile(pdf);
imgFile2 = pdf.readAsBytesSync();
imageString2 = base64Encode(imgFile2);
//print(imageString2);
note.photoname2 = imageString2;
note.type2 = 2;
decode2(imageString2);
setState(() {
  pdfdoc = true;
  doc = doc;

  imageFile = pdf;
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```dart
                    Container(

                            width: 120,
                            height: 120,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: PDFViewer(
                              document: doc,
                              zoomSteps: 1,
                              lazyLoad: false,
                            ),
                          )
```